Estimating the Posterior Probability of Playing Coin 1
Suppose someone has two coins with probability $p_1$ and $p_2$ of getting heads with $p_2\le p_1$. The person is throwing the coins and may switch from playing coin 1 to coin 2 with probability $\gamma$, however once they start playing the second coin they don't switch back to the first coin. We see the outcomes, however we don't know whether the person is playing the first coin or the second coin. How do we calculate the posterior probability that the coin the person is playing is the second coin given that we don't know the exact values of $p_1$, $p_2$, and $\gamma$?

If you want a Bayesian approach, you will need to start with a joint prior distribution for $p_1,p_2,\gamma$.  You can then find the likelihood for your observations, and update your prior distribution to a posterior distribution.  Both the likelihood and the updating may be complicated.

@Henry I am trying to simulate a problem where you have two options of either resetting to coin 1 with a certain cost vs possibly throwing the second coin and paying a cost each time a tail comes up with a higher probability [than coin 1]. The optimal solution is to check the posterior probability of the coin being the second one and resetting only if that probability is higher than a certain threshold. This is why I am asking this question. I am struggling to simulate the problem under optimal policy.

This seems conceptually similar to a Poisson change-point model, but with Bernoulli rather than Poisson observations.
Suppose that the person switches to the second coin after $m$ trials. We can write
$$
\begin{align*}
Y_1,\ldots,Y_m | p_1,p_2,m \sim \mathrm{Bern}(p_1) \\
Y_{m+1},\ldots,Y_n | p_1,p_2,m \sim \mathrm{Bern}(p_2)
\end{align*}
$$
If the probability of switching coins after each trial is constant ($\gamma$), we have
$$
m |\gamma \sim \mathrm{Geo}(\gamma)
$$
Finally, we need sensible priors for $p_1$, $p_2$, and $\gamma$.
Our goal is to sample from the posterior joint density of the parameters conditional on the observations,
$$
f(p_1,p_2,\gamma,m|\boldsymbol{y}), \, \text{ where } \, \boldsymbol{y}=\{y_1,\ldots,y_n\} ,
$$
but this is unlikely to be mathematically tractable.
Are you familiar with the Gibbs sampler? The idea is to set up a recursive sampling scheme where in each step you draw from the posterior density of one of the parameters, conditional on everything else.
If you choose your priors sensibly, these conditional distributions could be very simple. For example, the conditional distribution $f(\gamma|p_1,p_2,m,\boldsymbol{y})$ simplifies to $f(\gamma|m)$.
Starting with initial guesses $p^{(0)}_1$, $p^{(0)}_2$, $\gamma^{(0)}$, $m^{(0)}$, we want to:

Draw $m^{(1)}$ from $f(m|p^{(0)}_1, p^{(0)}_2, \gamma^{(0)},\boldsymbol{y})$.
Draw $p^{(1)}_1$ from $f(p_1|m^{(1)},\boldsymbol{y})$.
Draw $p^{(1)}_2$ from $f(p_2|m^{(1)},\boldsymbol{y})$.
Draw $\gamma^{(1)}$ from $f(\gamma|m^{(1)})$.

We then repeat the steps.
At first glance, step 1. is potentially a bit awkward, but the rest look straightforward.

Thank you! I am asking this question because I am trying to simulate the model 2 problem in this paper "Computing Optimal Quality Control Policies: Two Actions" by Robert Wang. When simulating the problem, I am unsure of how to find the posterior probability of the machine being in the bad state to compare to the threshold posterior probability.
